# X-Men fanfic starring misspelled X-Men and their logical powers

Tags: story-identification, x-men, fan-fiction

I was quoting [Rouge Angles of Satin](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RougeAnglesOfSatin) (Warning: TVTropes link!) to someone and it made me flash back to a fanfic I read, possibly on the FFML (FanFic Mailing List) around the year 2000, which had a story about the X-Men, but using common misspellings for their names and giving them powers that matched up with it. The part which has stuck with me, almost two decades later, was a scene where Rouge and whatever spelling they gave Gambit were making passionate love and the description was given of how the red makeup powder Rouge exuded was permanently staining the sheets.

I know... not much to go on. If I recall any more, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Flashing back to the X-Men parody characters in one of the early issues of *E-Man* published by First Comics in the early 1980s. Don't recall her *nom de guerre*, but I'm pretty sure the weather-controlling mutants actual name was "Ororeo". Grossest character was the Cyclops parody, Zit-Pops. Hope you get an answer - I wanna see!